# Deforming a plane over a topology

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I'm a newbie in Blender and I'm testing a numerical algorithm. However, I want to extract the topology distribution of some existing objects in the scene. In other words, I want a surface that describes the height distribution of the existing objects at a certain level (Step Function).

[image]

Imagine I have two cubes with different dimensions and I want to reflect those ups and downs as a piecewise function but over a plane.

[image]

I do not want to use the cloth modifier because, as far as I understand, it takes some time and I need something in real time. See the attached pics.

Comment: Look into the [shrinkwrap modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Destructive workflow (easy but requires joining meshes)

- first put another plane, the same size as your probe plane, just below the two objects, to represent the zero level
- Join all the "target" meshes (including the "zero" plane, excluding the probe plane) in a single object, by selecting all of them and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
- Subdivide your probe plane as much as the resolution you require

  [image]
- On your probe plane, add a Shrinkwrap Modifier. Use your target mesh as "target", and the options: "Project", "On surface", Axis: "Z", both "Negative" and "Positive"

  [image]
- In the viewport you will see an overlap between your probe and your target (which is what you wanted! but it looks weird). So I applied the modifier (<kbd>Apply</kbd>) and moved the probe a bit up, and used X-Ray for visualisation purposes:

  [image]

Add: with a Catmull-Clark Subsurface Modifier and a purpose-made shader:

[image]

or you could even duplicate the object (without subdivision surface!), and on the duplicate use a black material and a *Wireframe* modifier to make it look more like a plot:

[image]

### Non-destructive workflow

You will need:

- a zero-level plane, with one "Boolean" modifier of type "Union" for each object in your scene. This way, you will be able to modify the objects separately, while their changes will be reflected real-time on the "zero-level" plane
- your target plane, with

  - Shrinkwrap set as in the workflow above, using the "zero-level" plane as a target
  - A Displace modifier without texture, acting only along the Z axis
  - A shader like the one above

This is the result:

[image]

And the file (**requires Blender 2.8 and may not be compatible with post-Alpha versions**):

[image]

Comment: A couple of caveats: (**1**) Joining the target meshes together, and "Apply"-ing the Shrinkwrap modifier are not suitable for real-time, interactive, changing topology. I don't know however what you mean by "real time". (**2**) You mention step functions in your question but it's not too clear to me what quantity you want to make discrete: your matlab/matplotlib/whatever plot mock-up seems to be smooth up to a given resolution, so I tried to address that example rather than your words.

Comment: It's good enough for me so far. Many thanks indeed. I'm using Python scripting at the moment and I can manage those recursive steps in my algorithm. The quality of course in this process is highly dependent on the mesh. I'll maybe export it to matplotlib.

Comment: I've added an "interactive/non destructive" version of my answer just in case! Good luck with your project.